# Getting error when trying to extract message from .failure case (Swift/Combine)

Tags: swiftui, combine

```
API.Post(model: Model( 
name: name,
age: age
}    
.sink {[weak self] err in
        switch err {
        case .failure(let error):
            if case let ErrorResponse.error(statusCode, data, error) = error {
                
                //Decode here...
                let data = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            }
        case .finished:
            break
        }
    } receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
       print($0)
    }
    .store(in: &subscribers)
```

I get this error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
Below is what I tried;

```
case .failure(let error):
            if case let ErrorResponse.error(statusCode, data, error) = error {
                
                //Decode here...
                let data = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            }
```

I am expecting to get the object from data

Comment: What is the `Failure` type of the publisher returned by API.Post?  Which line of your code is flagged with the ambiguous type message?  Offhand I would suggest `if let errorResponse == error as? ErrorResponse` as an interesting check to wrap around your handler.

Comment: HI @ScottThompson the error is on .store(in: &subscribers), I will also try what you have suggested